# How can I re-flag a question?

Tags: support, flagging

There are some posts which I have flagged and some action is genuinely required for those posts. I would say they are *recent*, but there were even more *recent* flags raised by me which were quickly acknowledged. But a few are still unattended/pending. I am not in a hurry to get them reviewed, but I just want to know that how do I again bring them to moderators' attention. Is there any way to *re-flag* a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "re-flag" a post, in particular not if you are talking about an "off-topic" flag, since users are allowed to flag (or vote) to close and reopen each post exactly once.

Furthermore, off-topic flags are *generally* not handled specifically by moderators, but by the user-driven close review queue. So while sometimes you may get "lucky" because a moderator acts on the post, generally you should not expect moderator attention for any off-topic flags. The processing time for these flags highly depends on how many users are currently reviewing them and whether the reviews are unanimous or not.

Comment: So, how do I surely know that my flag has been declined?

Comment: @FakeMod If you click on the "X helpful flags" in your profile, you will reach a page where you can see your individual flags and whether they are 'helpful', 'pending', 'disputed' or 'declined'.

Comment: But I don't see the "disputed" or the "declined" option.

Comment: @FakeMod That's because none of your flags have been disputed or declined so far - good work!

Comment: There are also times that a flag is dismissed by a moderator even if no action is taken. I know sometimes I see something flagged that I don't agree with per se, but appreciate a user bringing it to our attention. There are other times when a flag is good because it makes me look at something, but it turns out to fix itself before I need to do something. I'll mark those helpful, even if there isn't any visible action taken.

Comment: @ACuriousMind How do I reinstate the "aged away" flags?

Comment: @FakeMod You don't - as I said, each user can flag or vote to close each post exactly once. "Aged away" means that not enough reviewers voted on the post one way or the other in about 2 weeks.